# Informix Outer Joins

Tags: sql

I have a query which is below. This query should return multiple rows but only returns two as some rows dont have a joining row in the status table.Can anyone help me to fix this query so that it counts all rows even if there are no joining rows in the status table.

```
SELECT count(h.h1_id)
FROM h1 h, owner o, ent e, status s
WHERE o.owner_id = h.owner_id AND e.enterprise_id = h.enterprise_id AND
h.herd_id=s.o_id AND s.o_type='H' AND h.code = 'QWE'
AND s.group_code!='123' AND s.status_code!='ABC'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Searching for `Informix Outer Join`, the second result was [an official looking tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst104.htm) which describes both the informix specific (if needed, if you're on a truly archaic version) and ANSI standard ways to do outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(h.h1_id)
FROM h1 h
INNER JOIN owner o
ON o.owner_id = h.owner_id
INNER JOIN ent e
ON e.enterprise_id = h.enterprise_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN status s
ON h.herd_id=s.o_id 
where h.code = 'QWE'
AND ((s.o_type='H' AND s.group_code!='123' AND s.status_code!='ABC') OR (s.oid is null))
```